# Can I stop a touchscreen device from selecting an image in Sheets whilst running assigned script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have set up a sheet that has several buttons (images with an assigned script) for adjusting the values of cells. This functions fine when used on a computer with a mouse but when used on a touchscreen device, clicking the button once both runs the script and selects the image for editing.

This selecting then makes it impossible for the script to be run again, using that button, without manually de-selecting the button to use it again (something I want to avoid). I have tried adding `.setActiveSelection()` to my script but unfortunately, this does not de-select the image, only changes the active cell.

Comment: I would put the buttons on a sidebar with html and connect to the server with Javascript and google.script.run.

Comment: I don't think it's recommended to assign scripts to images in mobile. In some OS (in Android, for sure) it is not possible to run the script at all. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

It's pretty simple.  It's all gs code.  No need for html files.  The html is all created server side.

```
function buttonDialog() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<style>input[type="button"]{margin:2xp 5px 2px 0;}</style>';
  var fnA=['func1','func2','func3','func4','func5'];
  var btnA=['name1','name2','name3','name4','name5'];
  fnA.forEach(function(btn,i){
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><input type="button" value="%s" onClick="google.script.run.%s()" />',btnA[i],fnA[i]);
  });
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}

function func1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Button 1 was clicked');
}

function func2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Button 2 was clicked'); 
}

function func3() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Button 3 was clicked'); 
}

function func4() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Button 4 was clicked'); 
}

function func5() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Button 5 was clicked'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this, the solution works perfectly. Could you please point me in the direction of a guide where I can find information on how to format these buttons? The layout is a little tight for a touchscreen.

Comment: You could add css to the dialog via style tags.  In fact there is a style tag in there.